# Save Image as local file or as binary data IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data

For this question there are many answers but i did not understand for some specific difference between them so i will post what i need and then question.

**About My Project:**
 i have image which has an effect added Gaussian blur and things like this, memory is optimized well. when i save my image the last step will be to show them on `UITableView`. The count of images will be from 30 to 60. If i capture the high quality image memory will be up to 200 MB so `UITableView` will add the additional memory of course. (WILL BE CRASHED!). At this moment i save images in `CoreData` and before UITableView i generate thumbnails to decrease memory.

**My Question:**

Instead of using `CoreData` its better to save images locally? In what it will help `UITableView` and how will it affect on memory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the gist, I have some suggestion regarding how you could achieve it in little bit cleaner way. **This is of course untested code and should only be used as inspiration**.

The idea is to have a cleaner cellForRowAtIndexPath and try working with list of models where the data is already set. So that the UITableViewDataSource only reads existing data. This guarantees good performance. So after you have downloaded your data, try to make models of it, that you use later on in your UITableViewDataSource methods, such as "cellForRowAtIndexPath" and "numberOfRowsInSection"

What really needs cleanup in the **untested code below** is how/when you create the models from the data you download. Can you maybe download all data simultaneously and then convert all objects to models and then reload the tableview?

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    // The UITableViewDataSource class contains a list TimeLineCellModels, which is used in numberOfRowsInSection
    var models: [TimeLineCellModel] = []

    //MARK: - Private Methods
    func addModel() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
            var imageDataFinal = task.document
            var finalImage = UIImage(data: imageDataFinal as NSData)
            let size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(finalImage!.size, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.2, 0.2))
            let hasAlpha = false
            let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, !hasAlpha, scale)
            finalImage!.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))
            let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            var model = TimeLineCellModel(task.documentName, documentDateString: task.createdOn, documentImage, scaledImage)
            self.models.append(model)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        })
    }

    private func modelForIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> TimeLineCellModel {
        return models[indexPath.row]
    }

    //MARK: - UITableViewDataSource Methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimeLineCell
        let model = modelForIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell.updateWithModel(task)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let rowCount = models.count
        return rowCount
    }
}

class TimeLineCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var documentName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var documentDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var documentImage: UIImageView!

    func updateWithModel(model: TimeLineCellModel) {
        documentImage.image = model.documentImage
        documentName.text = model.documentName
        documentDate.text = "Created On: \(model.documentDateString)"
    }
}

class TimeLineCellModel {
    var documentName: String
    var documentDateString: String
    var documentImage: UIImage

    init(documentName: String, documentDateString: String, documentImage: UIImage) {
        self.documentName = documentName
        self.documentDateString = documentDateString
        self.documentImage = documentImage
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test it and let you know performance changes

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to save the images locally, in the Documents directory and then storing the path to the image in Core Data. I don't think there is any advantage of storing the image as binary in Core Data over saving it on the disk since you are never going to fetch objects based on their binary properties.

In addition, I believe loading the image from disk is faster than loading it from the binary. I find `imageWithData:` useful when progressively downloading large image from the web.

You could also have a look at [this article](http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2012/04/19/ios-imagenamed-vs-imagewithcontentsoffile/) to see that `imageWithContentsOfFile:` has a small memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

Is it important to save the images offline? Which is the purpose of CoreData in my opinion.

How do you fetch the images?

I would suggest that you use [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) and include [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and take a look at [this category (extension) for UIImageView](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h) which makes fetching image super easy and also enables **caching**. Which is what you want for performance. (Since AFNetworking is an Objective-C library, do not forget to import the .h file in your [bridging header file](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html))

How are you blurring the images? Are you using [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView)? Are all images blurred? The problem here is that only the original image will be cached, but the blurring would take effect when scrolling in the UITableView, which is bad for performance.

How are you dequeuing your UITableViewCells? Can you paste your "cellForRowAtIndexPath"? Maybe you could store the blurred images in a model array which you could use to populate the UITableViewCells, so when returning to a cell, you could use this "manually cached" blurred image?

EDIT: Sorry proposed solution above still uses the memory, which is what you said does not work.

Using the Document directory as proposed by the other user is maybe the best solution? I think that CoreData introduces quite a big overhead in terms of code amount and maybe even performance?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. effects on image i am doing with openCV extension and the saving it. main purpose is that in TableViewCell i show low quality images with thumbnails so in my case its not important to show the blured image on tableview.And the images are loaded in offline mode (Camera or Library) here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath snippet: https://gist.github.com/geowarsong/e20acd0a9ea9e2f32842

Comment: Why don't you use caching instead of resampling the image every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called? You could use an `NSCache` where you can put the `scaledImage` instead of doing all the work over and over again. Before` dispatch_async` you could check if the image already is cached and only if not do all the work and cache it.

Comment: @skyddict 1 could you comment on gist your version?